# Remove/onDisconnect not working on log out

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), I created the following presence function:

```
     function setPresence() {
      var myConnectionsRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid + '/connections');
      var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
      connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
        if (snap.val() === true) {
          var con = myConnectionsRef.push();
          con.onDisconnect().remove();
          con.set("profile");
        }
      });
    }
```

I have the basic [sign out function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth):

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

The issue is that onDisconnect does not seem to activate on sign out. I need to clear user state when they log out, but for some reason, I am getting permission denied error:

Using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#remove), I tried the following when auth state changes such that user is undefined:

```
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid ).remove()
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Remove succeeded.");
          window.location = "/";
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
        });
```

I am using the basic security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing a user out from Authentication is unrelated to having a connection to the Realtime Database. While *your* security rules may require the user to be signed in, there is no such requirement on the product level: many apps allow part of their data to be used by unauthenticated users.

The `.info/connected` listener is `true` when the client can connect to the Firebase Realtime Database servers, and is not related to whether they can access specific data in that database.

Any `onDisconnect` handlers you define for a connection are executed when (the server detects that ) the connection is lost. This again is unrelated to the sign in state of the user.

If you want to mark the user as no longer present when they're signing out, you should remove their presence node **before** you sign them out. So your `firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid ).remove()` need to run (and complete) *before* you call `firebase.auth().signOut()`.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid ).remove().then(() => {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    window.location = "/";
  });
})
```